# R forecast autoplot or hchart

Tags: r, highcharts, arima, forecast

would like to do multiple arima time series plot for each - Cooked and market - as shown in the image below. Have tried both autoplot and hchart but both does not work. Please advise and assist. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
forecast1<-ts(lapply(arima, function(x) forecast(auto.arima(x), level=95)))

autoplot(forecast1)
hchart(forecast1)
```

[image: Data:]

Comment: Right now we can't tell exactly what your problem is or what you want your finished chart to look like - could you please edit your question to include [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), specify what you mean by "does not work" (error message? or plot doesn't look as expected?), and show us what you want the plot to look like.

Comment: Need a lot more info

Answer (score 1):

I took the step of turning the data into a time series before using the forecast algorithm.  Then printing the chart is just a matter of using apply on the new list that is generated.  Please see the code below.

```
Year <- seq(2012, 2018)
Cooked <- c(157.4, 157.2, 168.8, 192.3, 201.8, 233.4, 241.2)
Market <- c(51.7, 44.9, 49.5, 53.6, 57.2, 54.1, 53.5)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year, Cooked, Market))
ts_df <- ts(df[, -1], start = 2012, frequency = 1)

library(forecast)
forecast1<-lapply(ts_df, function(x) forecast(auto.arima(x), level=95))

lapply(forecast1, function(x) autoplot(x))
```

I recommend in future questions, putting the data together in a similar script to help us help you.